# How to run system commands in the backgroud on Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

When I type a command and make it run on Windows XP, a black DOS screen always flashes.

So how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Hidden Start](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html).